# Ubuntu 13.10. After login, no desktop displayed. Two Nvidia Graphics Cards, Four Monitors

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I am working on an issue with my Ubuntu 13.10 installation. I am attempting to get 4 monitors up and running but I am having some trouble.  So far, I installed and updated to the latest NVIDIA drivers (331.20). Initially X would not start (after installation) so I replaced my xorg.conf with xorg.conf.failsafe.  This fixed that problem, but then I tried to enable the other 2 monitors (other video card) and xorg fails to start once again (after I login there is no desktop).  I am fairly new to linux but I am not a complete beginner, but I'm not comfortable  poking around too much on my own to troubleshoot yet....

lspci -nn | grep VGA:

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 [GeForce GTX 570 Rev. 2] [10de:1086] (rev a1)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 [GeForce GTX 580] [10de:1080] (rev a1)
```

It seems that the nvidia-settings tool does not result in a good xorg.conf file.
 Here it is:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-05)  Wed Oct 30 18:20:32 PDT 2013

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Default Layout"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection
...    
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "SHARP HDMI"
    HorizSync       15.0 - 68.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 76.0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SyncMaster"
    HorizSync       0.0 - 0.0
    VertRefresh     0.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Configured Video Device"
    Driver         "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 570"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 580"
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Default Screen"
    Device         "Configured Video Device"
    Monitor        "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +640+0, DVI-I-3: nvidia-auto-select +0+1080"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-2: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

no support for 2d in 13.04/10 if you wish to do 2 video cards I would suggest 12.04/10 as it still had 2d support.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem at the moment and I've been pulling my hair out trying to get it working.

I have:

- Ubuntu 13.10 64bit
- 2 x nVidia NVS300
- 319.60 nVidia drivers

I recommend using just two screens (on the same adapter) with TwinView enabled and forgetting about the third screen for now. That's what I've done in the hope that something changes soon that makes multiple screens on multiple nVidia adapters possible.

Comment: I think that this is a bug/limitation of ubuntu right now.  I had stopped using linux because of this issue many years ago. I wanted to switch back to linux, I thought that it had been long enough that this issue would have been addressed (now-a-days lots of people have multiple video cards).  Perhaps, I was premature... This seems like a major limitation in the ubuntu world right now.  I hope it is resolved soon, so I can put ubuntu on the rest of my machines!!